# Web Design & Angular Js Tools

Tags: html, angularjs-scope

I am Java developer before  but now i am starting to work only on UI. I have little experience with UI. So I need a tool for Html 5.0, css 3.0, & angular Js.

Comment: A tool for html, css, and js? Any text editor will do. Also, keep in mind, "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 1):

Taking the comment above into account it is right for me to say the following answer is based on assumption but here we go:

I'm not quite sure what you mean by tools but if you mean a program to create your code in I would personally recommend [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or [Atom](https://atom.io/).

If you mean tools that are easily available to you to test and play around with your code then there are a number that are available to you, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) and [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/) are just a few.

I personally use Codepen as it has a nice and easy to use interface and I like the community around it, the homepage features a "picked" section which showcases user created content, it does however seem to have a heavy focus on "pretty" projects rather than functional ones. The editor it offers allows users to use a number of HTML, CSS and Javascript processors as well as use libraries such as Angular and JQuery. I created multiple angular projects using Codepen so I know it is capable of that and it is also really easy to implement it into a pen/project.

I hope this has answered the question but please remember that this is all my opinion each one of these things has their own strengths and weaknesses and overall the choice should be yours.

Comment: Great Thanks. I need a drag & drop tool for html & css like IDE.

Comment: If you are dead set on using and IDE type program then Adobe Dreamweaver is the best for web development in this instance however Dreamweaver is widely recognised as heavy and unecessary, again it's all personal preference, if you are set on learning UI I suggest just doing it and big fixing along the way, another advantage of Codepen is you can bug fix as you code through their use of live error flagging. But yeah if you want it to be IDE dreamweaver is probably the best bet.